# Maximum Likelihood with a sign restriction

Tags: maximum-likelihood, profile-likelihood, restrictions

Suppose that we have a log-likelihood function of five parameters and an observed data sample $y=[y_1,\ldots,y_N]$:
$$\mathcal{l}(\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3, \beta_4, \beta_5;\;y) =\log f_Y(y;\;\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3, \beta_4, \beta_5)$$
where $f_Y$ is a proper density function.

In my setup, $\beta_1\beta_2-\beta_3\beta_4$ should be strictly positive and **close to zero** by construction.

However, due to the randomness of the estimator, $\hat{\beta}_1\hat{\beta}_2-\hat{\beta}_3\hat{\beta}_4$, sporadically the estimates are negative.

Here, is there a way to restrict the sign of the estimates to be strictly positive?

If I need the sign restriction for only one parameter, say $\beta_1$, I will use the well-known profile-likelihood method.

(i.e. for each grid point of $\beta_1$ in an interval $(0,\;100]$, get the values of the log-likelihood, and then choose the grid point maximizingng the value and corresponding $[\hat{\beta}_2, \;\hat{\beta}_3, \;\hat{\beta}_4, \;\hat{\beta}_5$])

I am not sure, but, whether it is also possible to restrict the sign of a non-linear function of the parameters, $\beta_1\beta_2-\beta_3\beta_4$.

Comment: You can introduce an indicator function  $I_{[\beta_1\beta_2-\beta_3\beta_4>0]}$ which in the log-likelihood could be additive, taking the value $+0$ when the condition is met and $-\infty$ when it is not

Comment: @Henry So, you mean, by adding $I[\beta_1\beta_2 - \beta_3\beta_4>0]$ appropriately in the log-likelihood function, we use a modified log-likelihood function that is exactly the same as the original one if $\beta_1\beta_2 - \beta_3\beta_4>0$ is true and extremely small if that is not. Right? Maybe, $\mathcal{l}(\beta; y) + 1000\cdot 1[\beta_1\beta_2-\beta_3\beta_4>0]-1000$ could be a candidate.